# Authentication fails in Win 10 IoT Insiders preview build 10.0.17035.1000

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

There is an authentication problem in Win 10 Insiders preview build 10.0.17035.1000. When I try to open Device Portal from Win 10 IoT Dashboard, Device Portal cannot recognize the set up password.

When I run PowerShell as admin and execute the command "Enter-PSSession –ComputerName xx.xxx.xx.xx–Credential xx.xxx.xx.xx\Administrator", the authentication again fails with the message: "Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server xx.xxx.xx.xx failed with the following error message : Access is denied...."

I just verified that the Win 10 IoT Core build 10.0.16299.15 does not have this problem. But, unfortunately it does not have the updates in the Insiders Preview build 10.0.17035.1000  I need to correctly run my application.

Please advise me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Also, today there was probably an update of in Win 10 Insiders preview build 10.0.17035.1000 in my Raspberry Pi 3 boards which caused the Dashboard to require authentication for remote devices reset and shutdown operations. I think that this is unnecessary and inconvenient.

Comment: I had to use the default password of “p@ssw0rd” to login even though I had provided a different one when setting up micro sd

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is under investigation. The same issue has been posted in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/639ea668-86bd-437f-ad68-fe04e06cd6f2/win-10-iot-build-17030-does-not-recognize-correct-password?forum=WindowsIoT). If there is further update, i will let you know.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I have a deadline to deploy my application to my Raspberry Pi 3 boards for pre-production testing. And I cannot do this without accessing the Win 10 IoT file structure from my PC remotely. Is there some other way to deploy my application?

Comment: As alital mentioned, you can use default password of 'p@ssw0rd' to login.And then,please use [Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal) to change the password to yours different one.That will be ok.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will try to use the default login settings.

Comment: Hi Michael. This worked as usual but I really need the authenticated access to Win 10 IoT devices.